# Only Boolean Field = True to show, How to write in the template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, boolean

Hey everyone and sorry for my english,
I'm very new to Django and web-development so here is my question:

I have a model/table with only Boolean Fields and want to show them in my detail.html but ONLY the columns which are True. How can I manage this? I have tried to do it with a query but it doesn't worked. Now I have a solution where my template shows the Boolean Fields as checkboxes but it doesn't synchronize with the real values. So I have an problem with my input I think. I have tried it with and ifequal but it just turns it always True. Here is my template part of one Boolean Field:

```html
 <div class="form-row field-firstfield">
      <div class="checkbox-row">
         <input id="id_firstfield" name="firstfield" type="checkbox" value="on" {% ifequal Table.firstfield true %}checked="checked"{% endifequal %} disabled /><label class="vCheckboxLabel" for="id_firstfield">First Field</label>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want something like this?  `{% if Table.firstfield %}<div class="form-row field-firstfield">...</div>{% endif %}`

Comment: The query is the right way to do this. You should show the one you tried that didn't work, and what happened instead.

Comment: Done, see answer below :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok from the beginning:
Table:

```
class YNModel(models.Model):
Patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
firstfield = models.BooleanField(default=False)
secondfield = models.BooleanField(default=False)
thirdfield = models.BooleanField(default=False)
fourthfield= models.BooleanField(default=False)
fifthfield = models.BooleanField(default=False)



def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('main:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Django.views:

```
def table_list(request):
queryset = table.objects.all()
context = {
    "object_list":queryset,
    "title" : "List"
}
return render(request, 'main/detail.html', context)
```

template:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                <div class="well">
                    <h2>Risk Factors</h2>
                    {% for obj in object_list%}
                    {{obj.firstfield}}
                    {{obj.secondfield}}
                    {{obj.thirdfield}}
                    {{obj.fourthfield}}
                    {{obj.fifthfield}}
                    {{obj.sixtfield}}
                    {% endfor%}
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

When I run this I became just an empty list. My thought was that this is because of the BooleanFields.